# How to set paragraph's first two lines and last two lines keep together in IText 7?

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

There's a requirement for creating PDF by IText7 that the paragraph's first line cannot be drawn at the bottom of page, and paragraph's last line cannot be drawn at the top of page.

So my question is how to set paragraph's first two lines and last two lines keep together?

Thanks!

**Not acceptable:**

[image]

**Acceptable:**

[image]